# How to change FolderbrowserDialog Title in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I found some indirect methods to change the title in C#. But Is there any way to change the title in VB.

```
  Dim folderbrowser As New FolderBrowserDialog()
```

for openfiledialog there is direct method.But I need a folder browser

Comment: Set the Description property to give the user a hint why you are displaying the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe you can - at least without an unmanaged api call of some sort.

You can though change the Description which appears above tree in the dialog.

See here for docs on that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.description(v=vs.110).aspx

Re methods you found in C# to do thi.  Well - if you did - you could implement it in VB.Net.  You can basically do virtually anything in VB.net that you can do in C# - so you should be able to write VB.Net code that does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

vb.net

```
Dim dlg  as  FolderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog()
dlg.Description = "Select the document folder"
Dim result As DialogResult = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
```

c#

```
FolderBrowserDialog dlg = new FolderBrowserDialog();
dlg.Description = "Select the document folder";
DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
```